# 2 sublime-text installed and I would like to remove the old one

Tags: apt, dpkg, sublime-text

I've been using Sublime Text 3.2.2 Build 3211 (2006-2019) for a while till there is a prompt to upgrade it which is quite annoying. So, I installed a new one to get rid the pop up message.

[image]

Clicked `Download` and it redirected me to https://www.sublimetext.com/download

I followed [the steps given](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt) to install the new version.

But now there is 2 Sublime Text installed in Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I open a code, the old version is used by default instead of the new one.

```
1. 3.2.2 Build 3211 (2006-2019)
2. Stable version (2006-2021)
```

I would like to remove the old version. However, I can't locate the location of the old version in Ubuntu.

**apt**

```
wolf@linux:~$ apt list sublime*
Listing... Done
sublime-merge/apt/stable 2056 amd64
sublime-merge/apt/stable 2056 arm64
sublime-text/apt/stable,now 4107 amd64 [installed]
sublime-text/apt/stable 4107 arm64
wolf@linux:~$
```

**dpkg**

```
wolf@linux:~$ dpkg -l sublime*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-======================================================================
ii  sublime-text   4107         amd64        Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
wolf@linux:~$
```

How do I locate the old one and remove it?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the installation is saved to the default location, you can find Sublime Text in `/opt/sublime_text`. If you would like to find all of the files that start with Sublime (in the event you are looking for additional locations), you can do so with `find`:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "sublime*"
```

<sup>**Note:** Using `sudo` will allow you to search all locations, those where the current user does not have permission.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Sublime-text3 is available as a snap. I would suggest uninstalling both and reinstalling with:

`snap install sublime-text --classic` .

This way you get (semi) automatic updates.

If the version is not new enough for you, look into 'snap channels.' You can get newer version's, although snap store hasn't tested them as vigorously, so they are not yet on the 'stable' (default) channel.

That said, I am going off memory, so I would recommend googling it yourself. It is actually very useful knowledge. You'll find yourself using it time & again.

The older version is easy enough to delete, but you will find yourself doing this every time it updates.

EDIT: Just checked. The stable default channel will give you build 3211, whereas the 'edge' channel will give you build 4107 (which I am guessing is what you just upgraded to -- It was just released this month.)

Coincidentally, auto-updated installs for both of your current versions are available through the snap store.

The command above will give you 3211.

for 4107, add the flag `--edge`

At any time, to find out which versions are available (even if you have not downloaded) you can run:

`snap info sublime-text`

Comment: 3211 & 4107 are the version that I'm using now. I already mentioned this in my question. 3211 is the one that keeps asking for an update, and it was installed via snap (similar command that you shared)

Comment: Exactly! That is what I am saying. You can install either as a snap and not have to worry about upgrading. Snap does that for you. Installing directly via tarball means that every time that number changes, you'll be reinstalling and deleting a version.

Comment: That is why I mentioned those numbers. If you have the option to install via snap or apt, why keep the tarball. The only reason I cn think of is if tarball offers newer version which you want / need. I was saying that this isn't the case here.